# Why am I seeing half of my PHP code displayed in a browser?

Tags: php

I'm currently creating a login screen and am having some issues with some the code.  I have 4 basic boxes for a user to fill in, username, email, password & confirm password and once they do this they hit submit. But when they do this my browser throws out code from halfway in my php file.

I'm using Wampserver and it's all green and connected fine, the home page loads up  as normal too. It's just when they click submit it all goes awry.

I've tried various fixes such as updating my httpd.conf file and checking the apache modules but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3r3V.png)

Thanks,
Mat

Comment: All the code is there, just the `<?` makes an HTML element so it doesn't display. View the source. Do you have PHP installed? Are you using short tags? Without the code the best we can do is link you to the dup.

Comment: No I'm using <?php tags

Comment: Then your PHP isn't properly configured. If you view source, you'll see *all* of your PHP code there.

Comment: I understand that it's in the source, but when they click submit, it should say signup successful and store their details in a MYSQL database I've connected, but instead it returns partial code as shown in the screenshot

Comment: Why are you submitting to a `.inc.php` file? That implies it is an *include* and not a whole page.

Comment: I have a signup.php file (first screen the user sees) that has an include in it. This is including 'signup.inc.php' where the code is stored based on what action the user performs, in this case entering details to sign up.

Comment: Hi All, just wanted to drop a message to say I solved the issue, I was pointing to the localhost port 8080 which was not the MySQL server port of 3306, in my database connection php file.